Understanding the Reasoning Behind the Growth Function $m_{\mathcal{H}}(N)=2^N$ for Convex Sets
I am currently reading Learning from Data by Abu-Mostafa et al. and I am struggling to understand the reasoning behind the growth function $m_{\mathcal{H}}(N)=2^N$ for convex sets. Here is the relevant context:
Consider a hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ consisting of all hypotheses in two dimensions $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow$ $\{-1,+1\}$ that are positive inside some convex set and negative elsewhere (a set is convex if the line segment connecting any two points in the set lies entirely within the set).
To compute $m_{\mathcal{H}}(N)$ in this case, we need to choose the $N$ points carefully. According to the book, we should choose $N$ points on the perimeter of a circle. Now consider any dichotomy on these points, assigning an arbitrary pattern of $\pm 1$ to the $N$ points. If you connect the +1 points with a polygon, the hypothesis made up of the closed interior of the polygon (which has to be convex since its vertices are on the perimeter of a circle) agrees with the dichotomy on all $N$ points. For dichotomies that have less than three +1 points, the convex set will be a line segment, a point, or an empty set. This means that any dichotomy on these $N$ points can be realized using a convex hypothesis, so $\mathcal{H}$ manages to shatter these points and the growth function has the maximum possible value
$$
m_{\mathcal{H}}(N)=2^N
$$
Notice that if the $N$ points were chosen at random in the plane rather than on the perimeter of a circle, many of the points would be 'internal' and we wouldn't be able to shatter all the points with convex hypotheses as we did for the perimeter points. However, this doesn't matter as far as $m_{\mathcal{H}}(N)$ is concerned, since it is defined ba: $\downarrow$ on the maximum (which is $2^N$ in this case).
My question is: Why does the arrangement of points on the perimeter of a circle guarantee that the hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ can shatter the points, thus leading to $m_{\mathcal{H}}(N)=2^N$ ? Specifically, I am confused about why any dichotomy can be realized with a convex set in this setup.

For a set $\cal P$, let  $\mathrm{conv}(\cal P)$ denote the convex hull of $\cal P $, i.e., the set of points that arise by taking all possible convex-combinations of points in $\cal P$. We will say that a finite set $\mathcal{S}$ is in convex position if for every $x \in \mathcal{S}, x \not\in \mathrm{conv}(\mathcal{S}\setminus \{x\}),$ that is, if no $x \in \mathcal{S}$ is a finite convex combination of other points in $\mathcal{S}$.
Now, note that if a finite set of points $\mathcal{S}$ is in convex position, then we can realise all $2^N$ dichotomies on $\mathcal{S}$ using convex sets. Indeed, to realise the dichotomy for which points $\cal P \subset \mathcal{S}$ are labelled $1$, and the rest $-1,$ simply use the convex set $\cal \mathrm{conv}(P)$. By definition, this contains every point in $\cal P$. Further, if a point $x' \in\mathcal{S}\setminus \cal P,$ then since $\mathcal{S}$ is in convex position, we cannot write $x'$ as a convex combination of points in $\cal P$, meaning that it is not in $\mathrm{conv}(\cal P)$.
Now, your question amounts to proving that any finite subset $\mathcal{S}$ of a circle is in convex position. It suffices to prove this for the unit circle (by scaling and translating, which don't affect the convexity properties (why?) ). Let $x$ be any point in $\mathcal{S}$. Then we want to show that $x \not\in \mathrm{conv}(\mathcal{S}\setminus \{x\})$. But, by rotating the picture, we can without loss of generality assume that $x = (1,0)$. Now note that every point in $\mathcal{S}\setminus \{x\}$ must have first coordinate $<1$, and so every point in $\mathrm{conv}(\mathcal{S}\setminus\{x\})$ must also have first coordinate $<1$. It follows that $x$ is not in this convex hull, and we're done.
You can also see the same argument more geometrically: let $y,z$ be the two closest points to $x$ along the circle. Then $\mathcal{S} \setminus \{x\}$ lies on one side of the straight line joining $y$ and $z$, while $x$ lies on the other side. Of course, if a set $\cal P$ lies in some halfspace, any convex combination of points in $\cal P$ also lies in that halfspace (why?), and we're done.
